# Fail with ab test with nginx, two workers and 1024 connections?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, benchmark, concurrency, ab

I'm doing some tests with nginx 1.4.1 and Node.js 0.10.5 on my development machine (P8700 Dual Core 2.53Ghz, 4Gb RAM running Xubuntu x64). Unfortunately I can't do `ab` with 100000 requests with a concurrency of 1000. I get this error after a fraction of the total:

> apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
>
> Total of 17641

Configuration file seems fine to me (2 workers, each handling 1024 connections at maximum):

```
worker_processes 2;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include           mime.types;
    default_type      application/octet-stream;
    sendfile          on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    upstream node_upstream {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
        server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass     http://node_upstream;
        }
    }
}
```

Workers are online (`ps aux | grep nginx`):

```
root     20833  0.0  0.0  22404  1292 ?        Ss   22:08   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/balancer.conf
nobody   21022  0.7  0.0  22916  1784 ?        S    22:15   0:03 nginx: worker process                                             
nobody   21023  0.7  0.0  22916  1784 ?        S    22:15   0:03 nginx: worker process
```

I don't think it's something related to my OS installation: I can do the same test with a Node.js cluster and it completes fine. Test completes with nginx and `ab -n 10000 -c 100`.